# ember.js: Transition to child route reloads parent's template

Tags: ember.js

I'm finding that when I transition to a different child route, the template associated with the parent route is also refreshed. I'd like to avoid the parent template "flickering", as it does not need to be updated.

Specifically, I have a router with two levels of nesting:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("first", {path: "/first/:first_id"}, function(){
    this.resource("second", {path: "/second/:second_id"}, function(){
      this.route("routeone");
    });
});
```

And corresponding templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="second"> 
Some stuff
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="second/routeone"> 
Some more stuff
</script>
```

The "first" and "second" routes just return the ids, e.g.:

```
App.SecondRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return {id: params.second_id};
  }
});
```

And the "routeone" route gets JSON from a URL:

```
App.SecondRouteoneRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params){
  var first_id = this.modelFor('first').id;
  var second_id = this.modelFor('second').id;
  var dataurl = "/_data/" + first_id + "/" + second_id;
  return Ember.$.getJSON(dataurl);
},
```

When I transition from /first/X/second/Y/routeone to /first/X/second/Z/routeone, the "Some stuff" text from the "second" template flickers. Can this be avoided?

Comment: Can you provide us the routes implemention?

Comment: Give internal resource as route.....they try.

Comment: Added the routes' implementation.